# Swift change thread qualityOfService / priority after thread run

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-priority

My iOS app got several threads (between 8 and 50) and when I set `qualityOfService` before thread starts, `.userInitiated` threads finishes before `.background` threads. But I need to change these priorities after calling `Thread.run()`. Changing `qualityOfService` does not affect after calling run. Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 1):

Without the knowledge of the problem you want to solve, I'd advice you;

Wouldn't it be more helpful using GCD which is why GCD is intended to? GCD will handle the threads lifecycle for you, therefore you would only need to worry about dispatching your work in one queue or another. You could use either dispatching or OperationQueues to fit your needs.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, I got an app that shows maps of buildings. There are several floors in each building and each floors data is stored in individual xml files. So I parse that xml files via threads for performance benefits. First floors xml are parsed at first, after that I need to parse other floors in background, but if user selects another floor, selected floors parsing priority should be the fastest. I will take look at GCD. If you have any other ideas that would be great.